# Rect Apexcharts - dynamic-loaded-chart (column chart) on bar click exec function error

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using [dynamic-loaded-chart](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/dynamic-loaded-chart/). When I click on any bar to see details, getting an error: **TypeError: react_apexcharts__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.exec is not a function**
Can anybody help?